# How can I get the value from the XML content below?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

How to get the value of the title tag?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response status="ok" permission_level="admin" message="ready to use" cached="0">
<title>johndoe</title>
</response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the XML is in `xml` then:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
jd  = doc.at('title').text
```

The CSS style [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) is probably the easiest approach for something like this. You could also use [XPath](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) if you prefer:

```
jd = doc.xpath('.//title').text
```